# press qml button but no response

Tags: qt, qml

I used the code below to setup a button

```
Button {
    x: 141
    y: 312
    width: 98
    height: 22
    text: qsTr("Hello World")
    anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 116
    anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: -59
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    MouseArea
            {
                anchors.rightMargin: 126
                anchors.bottomMargin: -172
                anchors.leftMargin: -126
                anchors.topMargin: 172
                preventStealing: true
                anchors.fill: parent
                onPressed: {
                    console.debug("clicked!")

                }


            }
}
```

press button 'hello world' it should display clicked on console.

but it looks like nothing happens when I click the button

[image]

Your comment welcome

Comment: QML Button has it own signal clicked, so you don't need MouseArea, use clicked signal

Comment: Ok, in this case I posted this as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `QML` `Button` has it own signal `clicked`, so you don't need `MouseArea`.

Secondly, if you want to use `MouseArea` you can try also `onClicked` signal and do this like this:

```
Button {
    id: button1
    x: 8
    y: 19
    text: qsTr("Button")
    //        onClicked:  {
    //            console.debug("clicked!")
    //        }
    MouseArea{
        preventStealing: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed: {
            console.debug("clicked!")
        }
        onDoubleClicked:
        {
            console.debug("double clicked!")
        }
    }
}
```

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-button.html#clicked-signal

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#clicked-signal